# Flutter VSCode, unable to android module in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

Hi I am trying to open Flutter android module in android studio by right clicking android folder and then " Open in Android Studio " but its doing nothing.

[image]

I have correctly setup `android-studio-dir` but still unable to open. I am using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Do you see a message in the bottom right corner that says it couldn't find Android Studio?

If not, click Help -> Toggle Developer Tools and see if there are any errors listed.

The code here is fairly simple, it just reads `android-studio-dir` and then appends the executable (`bin/studio.sh`). Do you have this file in your folder? If you execute it manually does it work?

Comment: There is neither a message in bottom corner nor in Toggle Developer Tools, and Yes I tried to execute it manually it executed successfully, When I use Intellij Idea then I gets that error in bottom corner.. but in case of vscode there's nothing happening..

Comment: Please open an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code and we can do some digging. It shouldn't silently do nothing whatever is wrong, so something definitely needs fixing :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. I've opened https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1897 to look at this. We previously tweaked this code to look for `studio.sh` instead of `studio` but now I'm wondering if that's not consistent. I'll change it to look for both.